# Imagemagick bold text

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I have an image which contains some text in it. My OCR software recognizes it properly only if the text is in bold. I was wondering if there is any way by which i can make the text in an image bold using ImageMagick before i send it to OCR.

Any help is appreciated.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase the bright or contrast:

http://www.imagemagick.org/www/command-line-options.html#brightness-contrast
http://www.imagemagick.org/www/command-line-options.html#contrast-stretch